# Pressing divide numpad key after pressing a letter behaves differently when it is pressed after a number?

Tags: textbox, arabic

I am developing a WPF application for arabic users using vb .net.
In the application the user has to enter in a textbox the following: "22/85/39" but unfortunately after entering it, it displays the reverse (i.e. 39/85/22).
This is my xaml code:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtWorkingNumber" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200"
                         Text="{Binding WorkingNumber}"
                         FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                         Language="ar-SA"
                         NumberSubstitution.Substitution="AsCulture"/>
```

I have tried all Substitution enumerations but failed to find the fix.
Could any one give me a help on how to fix it??
many thanx...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution which is, to add white space at the end of the text where you type "/" sympole. This is achieved through this code snippet added to the code behind:

```
Private Sub TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs)
    Dim myTextBox As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    If Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString.StartsWith("ar") Then
        If e.Key = System.Windows.Input.Key.Divide Then
            myTextBox.Text += " "
            myTextBox.CaretIndex = myTextBox.Text.Length
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```